# C#, converting string to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

In a C# project I am receiving a `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` and iterate over its keys, values

```
public static void info(JObject aInfoJSON){
 foreach(var it in aInfoJSON){
     if (it.Key.Equals("str")){/*do something*/}
     if (it.Value.Equals(?)){/*so something*/}
  }
}
```

here the `it.Key` type is `string` but the `it.Value` is `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken`. passing `"something"` never if condition becomes true nor passing `"{something}"` and `JToken.parse("something")` throws exception.

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: s. Path '', line 0, position 0.'

a sample received JObject is like : `{{  "name": "systems api",  "version": "11.0.7.72",  "apiVersion": "v1"}}`

How should I do this comparison ?

Comment: If you need to traverse the whole thing, deserializing it might be easier.  Otherwise - `throws exception` is vague and not helpful

Comment: What sort of object do you want `?` to be?  Should it correspond to a string-valued JSON primitive only, or could it be anything at all such as something that serializes to a JSON object or array?

Comment: @Disaffected1070452 edited question and added the exception

Comment: @dbc any type no matter just want to compare it. edited question. for instance for that JObject received for first iteration `it = {[name, systems api]}`. now any type that I can check `it.Value` is `system api`, string, number, hashcode,...

Comment: Neither `"{something}"` nor `"something"` is valid Json (hence why JToken.Parse complains). Since it seems from your question that you want to manually parse/process Json, i would recommend you (re-)familiarize yourself with the JSON data format.. ;-)

Comment: @elgonzo I know they are not JSON, `.Equals()` gets string thought it might cast or something to check if it is equal to that JToken. and I think you should read more about JSON and JToken

Comment: I guess you are right. I'll leave you to it. No time, i need to read about JSON and JToken

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi Problem with not with the Code which you have uploaded above. Problem is when you trying to parse your response content to produce your "JObject - aInfoJSON". Are you setting any JsonSettings while deserializing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JValue you can pick up the value type and implement something along those lines.

```
public static void info(JObject aInfoJSON){
  foreach(var it in aInfoJSON){
     if (it.Key.Equals("str")){/*do something*/}

  switch(it.Value.Type)
  {
    case JToken.String:
      if (it.Value.Value<string>().Equals("?"))
        {/*so something*/}
    case JToken.Float:
        if(it.Value.Value<Float>().Equals(0)); 
        {/*so something*/}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what I was searching for

Comment: @elgonzo if you were not successful with your readings, the answer is here